# javascript can't preload first image

Tags: javascript, image, load

So i want to make an image gallery and 99% of it works awesome. But there is one problem. First called image never center horizontally, others do. It look like there is some problem about preloading. My principle here is that i first preload images, than i create element IMG, set image to height of 500px, get the value of width and then center it horizontally.

Here is the code:

```
var slike = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];
var slike2 = ["image12", "image22", "image22"];

var sprem = function(ime, zacetek) {


        for (var f = 0; f < ime.length; f++ ) {
            var nalagati = new Image();
            nalagati.src = ime[f];
        }

        var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
        wrap.style.display="block";
        var prik = document.getElementById("prikaz");
        prik.style.display="block";
        var pus = document.getElementById("pus");
        pus.style.display="block";
        var pus2 = document.getElementById("pus2");
        pus2.style.display="block";

        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        img.setAttribute("id", "slik");            
        img.src=ime[zacetek];           
        img.style.position="relative";
        img.style.height="500px";
        img.style.top="15%";

        var sirina = img.width;
        var izracun = sirina / 2;


        img.style.marginLeft="-" + izracun + "px";            
        img.style.left="50%";

        img.style.border="5px solid white";                    



        document.getElementById("prikaz").appendChild(img);
        document.getElementById("izhod").style.display="inline";
        var x = document.getElementById("okvir");          


        window.ime = ime;
        window.zacetek = zacetek;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe set a delay for 20 milliseconds or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the image load takes some time, the statement `var sirina = img.width` will give wrong value if `img` has not loaded completely.

The best way is to do all the styling after the image has loaded completely. Like this:

```
img.onload = function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('slik');
    img.style.position="relative";
    img.style.height="500px";
    img.style.top="15%";

    var sirina = img.width;
    var izracun = sirina / 2;
    img.style.marginLeft="-" + izracun + "px";            

    img.style.left="50%";
    img.style.border="5px solid white";
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That totally works. I have spend hours figuring out this problem.